# Eject a USB modem in the scheduled tasks

Tags: usb, power, scheduled-tasks, eject

I need to schedule a task to eject a USB modem immediately when the power fail.

I had searched in EventLog and found the EventID for power Failure, put it in the Triggers,but in the Action I didn't know how to put what will eject the modem.

Can anybody please help me on this, I need it urgently, because my system crash on the power failure because of the USB modem. I have a UPS but I have no suitable power cable for the modem ( couldn't find one in my country ).

I run win7 Ultimate

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Microsoft utility [DevCon](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=311272).  Something like this should do:

```
devcon.exe remove @usb\device\identifier
```